# Does there exist a TM for all countable languages?

Tags: finite-automata, turing-machines, computability, countable

I know that if a Turing machine exists for a language, that language is recursively enumerable and therefor there exists a enumeration procedure for it. However, if a language is countable, does that mean that there must be a TM for it?

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computation theory, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

The set Σ* is a countable set, so all its subsets are countable. This means, in particular, that *every* infinite language is countable, even though not all infinite languages are recursively enumerable. Therefore, there are infinitely many infinite languages for which no TM exists.

Hope this helps!